# parseFloat return NaN javascript number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this problem where this code won't calculate anything in the `<tr>` tag.

```
function CashCategory()
        {
            $("#cashAmount"+counterCash).keydown(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                  var z1=$("#cashAmount"+counterCash).val();

                  var sum3 = 0;
                    $('.priceCash').each(function() {
                        sum3 += parseFloat($(this).text());
                    });
                    //$('#grandTotalGold').html(sum2.toFixed(2));
                    $('#grandTotalCash').val(sum3.toFixed(2));
                    //$('#grandTotalCash').text(sum3.toFixed(2));
                }, 0);

            });
        }
```

HTML Code

```
<td class="priceCash">
  <input type="text" id="cashAmount1" class="form-control" value="">
</td>
```

z1 produce value but when it goes under calculation. It when NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you using `z1` in your calculations anywhere. Furthermore, `$(this).text()` should always be empty since `td.priceCash` doesn't have any text inside of it.

Perhaps you really meant to do this?

```
    $("#cashAmount"+counterCash).keydown(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
              var sum3 = 0;
                $('.priceCash').each(function(i,el) {
                    sum3 += parseFloat($("input",this).val());
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.priceCash').each(function() {
      sum3 += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
```

text passed to `parseFloat` will be an empty string , so naturally you get `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to pass counterCash to the function as a variable:

function CashCategory(counterCash) {...}

Comment: counterCash set as global sir :)